# Auto updating radio check

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, radio-button

Got this: http://jsfiddle.net/NdsF8/

Want it to be dynamic so when you click a new radio button, it changed the written value.

I'm sure this has been covered somewhere, but for the life of me cannot find it.

If you're magical enough, either PHP, JQuery, or then Javascript. Any will do but thats my preferred order :]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add an event to do so :

http://jsfiddle.net/NdsF8/1/

Comment: Thank you thank you! Well it says 10 minutes before I give you the tick, but cheers.

Comment: note that you should use change() event instead of click() (the user can change radio buttons using keyboard)